# How should i get some value from javascript object and check for null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the element as

```
   var minPricePerInputField = $("input#A"+indexNr);
```

The element can be present also or not also. I am getting some [object Object] thing. I have no idea what is this. I am receiving this [object Object] when the element is not there.

Comment: If you use firebug (or another similar) you could breakpoint the code in the browser and take a look at the object, this would help you no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if(   $(minPricePerInputField).length === 0);
```

means null. no element for that selector.

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar nops It will be "===". Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735939/jslint-expected-and-instead-saw for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are recieveng jQuery object. When there's no such an element, the length property of the recieved object will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

`[object Object]` is the default `toString()` of an `Object`.

When the `Object` is used in a `String` context, the `toString()` is called implicitly.

Whether jQuery matched 0 or more elements won't affect the `toString()`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VWMxH/).

You can check the `length` property to check if the selector matched any elements.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ExEEQ/).

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of an object.. use `object.property`

Best way: using jQuery ...see the data by `console.log(minPricePerInputField)`

Comment: This will log `[Object object]`. Even if no matching elements are found, a transient jQuery object will still be created and returned...

Answer (score 0):

```
var minPricePerInputField = $("input#A"+indexNr);

if(minPricePerInputField.size()==1)
{
   //element exists do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("input#A"+indexNr).length == 1){
      alert("Im present");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check count of selected element count.

```
var minPricePerInputField = $("input#A"+indexNr);
if(minPricePerInputField.length == 0){
   return;
}
```