# How do you toggle the visibility of an html element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone could figure out why my function won't work properly. What I am trying to achieve is when a button is clicked it displays text and when it is clicked again it hides it and so on.

```
function hideshow (){
    var showhide=document.getElementById('text');
    if(showhide.style.display="none")
    {
        showhide.style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        showhide.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

So far I got it to display my text when I click it once, but once I click it again it has no effect on the text.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator... use `==` if you want to compare. Right now you're hiding it at the start of every click, then showing it again. Always.

Comment: Or even better, try to use `===` to compare. Learn about it first, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735939/jslint-expected-and-instead-saw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hideShow() {
    el.style.display != "none" ? "none" : "block";
}
```

Comment: Why does my text not display on my first click? I have my text set to onClick="hideshow();" but, it only runs on my second click. CSS for my text has display:none if that helps.

Comment: I still need to double click in order to get it to run. Don't worry about it, i'll search online for it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that should be:

```
function hideshow (){
    var showhide = document.getElementById('text');
    if (showhide.style.display == "none")
    {
        showhide.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        showhide.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

So, use '==' instead of '=' when comparing. The '=' operator assigns a value. In javascript there is also the '===' operator. The difference is that '==' will cast values, while '===' will compare strictly.

For example:

```
0 == false; // will return true
0 === false; // will not
```

So you can also use

```
if (showhide.style.display === "none")
```

You can read more about the operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

Comment: Indeed I did, changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

you should be using `===` in your `if` statment. `=` is an assignment operator:

```
function hideshow (){
    var showhide=document.getElementById('text');
    if(showhide.style.display==="none")
    {
        showhide.style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        showhide.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Or:

```
function hideshow (){
    var showhide=document.getElementById('text');

    showhide.style.display = showhide.style.display === "none" ? 
        "block" : 
        "none";  
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a `return false` after changing the display value?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the comparison `==` operator instead of assigning the value using the `=` operator.

Try:

```
function hideshow() {
    var showhide = document.getElementById('text').style;
    (showhide.display = showhide.display == "none" ?  "block" : "none" )
}
```

You can assign and compare in one statement using:

```
(showhide.display = showhide.display == "none" ?  "block" : "none" )
                  ^assign            ^comparison
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Eaf2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideshow() {
            var showhide=document.getElementById('text');
            if(showhide.style.visibility=="hidden")
            {
                showhide.style.visibility="visible";
            }
            else{
                showhide.style.visibility="hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <button onclick="hideshow()">hideshow</button>
</body>
</html>
```