# Why use strict comparision with return value of typeof

Tags: javascript

People tend to write

```
if (typeof(value) === "undefined")
{
  /* something */
}
```

but why is strict comparision used? typeof always evaluates to a string, doesnt it?

What not using

```
if (typeof(value) == "undefined")
{
  /* something */
}
```

?

Comment: See the accepted answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735939/jslint-expected-and-instead-saw In your example case, one of the reasons for using strict comparison is that it isn't always *certain* to the reader that `typeof` does in fact always return a string - just as it wasn't to you. It then follows that had `==` been used instead in your example, you would have been wondering "hmm, perhaps `typeof` can return a non-string value that, when coerced to string, evaluates as undefined?". :)

Comment: @bzlm—"*isn't always certain to the reader that typeof does in fact always return a string*" is a rather thin straw man. The behaviour has been defined in the language specification from the beginning and there are no known non-confirming user agents (and likely never have been), so any such reader shouldn't be writing code that matters. What about the unnecessary parenthesis? Will such a reader think *typeof* is a function? ;-)

Comment: "*People tend to write*" do they? "*why is strict comparision used*" perhaps because those people wish ECMAScript was strictly typed and are offended by the abstract comparison algorithm (the latter applies to the influential Douglas Crockford). Note that the parenthesis are redundant. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's not strictly necessary - as you said `typeof` always returns a string, but equally there is no compelling reason to use `==` either. I suspect most people just get into the habit of using strict equals by default, which is the reason you see it used in this situation more commonly.

Comment: JSLint and JSHint may have affected those habits. :)

Comment: == is a char less and signals that we already know about type equality. Such small signals have a value themselves.

Answer (score 1):

1. What we know good practice is using strict comparison(This is what we should make habit of!).
2. There are cases like the one you showed in your example, where there might not be necessity of using strict comparison.(also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736117/3556874 you can see we dont need `===`).
3. in this case i.e `typeof(value)`, there is no difference using `==` or `===`, so it will be a good practice to use `===` as a habit.

Comment: We seem to not agree about the good habitness, to me there is no difference between checking value+type and checking value+checking value again. Just in case.

Comment: Also, == is a char less and signals that we already know about type equality, which is important information.