# React will not update dropdown options,and does not match console.log statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, state

I cannot seem to figure out why my modal is not updating correctly. I've tried different vairation of useEffect, useMemo, useCallback and I get the same end results (differently). Whats happening is when the `Device` is selected when the modal is activated. The value should be pulled from that option and a list of objects is iterated over to find the matching id. Once found, the data for that is passed to `setDevices`. Two problems are occuring. ( The 1st .map() call works correctly, the 2nd .map() does not return anything, even with the overkill ternary statement)

Problem 1:
If I hard code an ID. Then modalData is updated. If I use e.target.value, and console log it, the console displays the correct ID but if I allow React to do the comparison, React always returns false.

Problem  2:
If `devices` are definitely populated and again, displaying in the console. Devices.map does not work and will not display the options.

It almost like the console and React are 2 different entities.  I have the log statements there so I know when the whole page is render or just the item. Both solutions I think would be ok, either re-rendering the modal or *better* would be only re-reindering the changed output.

I also use react-redux but I think its a bit overkill to make a dispatch and action for a modal thats used on 1 screen. This might be my last solution though.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function TCOAddModal({makes, display}){

    const displayModal = display ? {"display":"block"} :
        {"display":"none"} 

    function handleMakeNameChange(e){
        console.log('ID ', e.target.value)
        let printers = makes.filter(printer => printer.id === e.target.value)
        setModalData(prev=>{
            return({
                ...prev,
                devices:printers
            })
        })
        
    }  
    
    function handleBlur(e){
        handleMakeNameChange(e)
    }
    
    const [modalData, setModalData] = useState({
        device:'',
        devices:[],
        deviceQuantity:'',
        monthlyLease:0,
        monthlyMonoPages : '',
        monthlyColorPages: '',
        totalMonthlyPages:'',
        baseVolumeMono: '',
        baseVolumeColor: '',
        baseRateMono: '',
        baseRateColor: '',
        currentMonoCpp: '',
        currentColorCpp: ''
    })

    
    function handleModalData(e){
        const { name, value } = e.target
        console.log("modal data!", name)
        setModalData((prevValue) => {
            switch (name) {
                case "tcoDevice-makeName":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        TCOMakeName: value
                    };
                case "deviceQuantity":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        deviceQuantity: value
                    };
                case "monthlyLease":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        monthlyLeasePayment: value
                    }
                case "monthlyMonoPages":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        monthlyMonoPages: value
                    }
                case "monthlyColorPages":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        monthlyColorPages: value,
                    }
                case "totalMonthlyPages":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        totalMonthlyPages: value
                    }
                case "baseVolumeMono":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        baseVolueMono: value
                    }
                case "baseRateMono":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        baseRateMono: value
                    }
                case "baseVolumeColor":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        baseVolumeColor: value
                    }
                case "baseRateColor":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        baseRateColor: value
                    }
                case "currentMonoCpp":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        currentMonoCpp: value
                    }
                case "currentColorCpp":
                    return {
                        ...prevValue,
                        currentColor: value
                    }
                default:
                    console.log('Error setting value ')
            }
        })
    }
     


    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('TCOAddModaleffect: ')

    }, [makes, modalData.devices])
    console.log('Mounted in main body of TCOADDModal?')

    retutn(


...
                    <div className="cell medium-8 medium-offset-2">
                        <select id="tcoDevice-makeName" onBlur ={handleBlur} onChange={handleMakeNameChange} name="TCOMakeName">
                            <option defaultValue="-1"></option>
                            { makes && makes.map((printer, ix) => <option key={ix} value={printer.id}>{printer.name}</option>)}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-x align-middle modal-row">
                    <div className="cell medium-10 medium-offset-2">Device</div>
                    <div className="cell medium-8 medium-offset-2">
                        <select id="tcoDevice-shortName">
                            {modalData.devices && modalData.devices.length > 0 && modalData.devices.map(
                            device=>(
                                <option key={device.id}>{device.short_model}</option>
                            )
                        ) }</select>
                    </div>
                </div>
...



export default TCOAddModal
```

Answer (score 0):

ugh I fixed it. Simple Error. Filter returns a list, not a single object. Pull the first item from the list. I was also accessing the attribute incorrectly.
`let printers = makes.filter(printer => printer.id === e.target.value)`
was supposed to be
`let printers = makes.filter(printer => printer.id == e.target.value)[0]`
or
`let printers = makes.filter(printer => printer.id === Number(e.target.value))[0]`
==============================*
Also, JSlint threw me off with the `Expected '===' and instead saw '=='`
In my case, **==** was required, since `e.target.value` is a string.
[JSLint Expected '===' and instead saw '=='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735939/jslint-expected-and-instead-saw)